# Create ics / ical from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to render an event as ics and vcs. I have both builders setup

```
show.ics.erb
show.vcs.erb
```

But I'm not sure how to setup the view to respond accordingly. I've tried:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => "open_dashboard" }
  format.ics { }
  format.vcs { }
end
```

But that doesn't work. The log has:

```
Started GET "/events/1.vcal" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-27 11:47:36 -0500
  Processing by EventsController#show as 
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Consultation Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "event".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (34.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/open_dashboard (153.8ms)
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 237ms (Views: 124.5ms | ActiveRecord: 35.2ms)
```

So how do I get it to render the right view?

Comment: In addition to Martin Frosts answer wouldn't you want to say ```format.ics { @object }```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to register your custom mime types in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`?

Something like `Mime::Type.register "text/calendar", :ics` might do the trick for `.ics`.

Comment: I had done that. But it is a good reminder for others. In my case, I was being dumb and going to vcal / ical vs going to vcs and ics.

Comment: For others: since it is the default action to respond to those, you don't need the respond_to block.